# Dynamically get values from server by index generated in XML and place by div java

Tags: java, xml, cgi

I have device and need get values from the server and place in the right place by DIV.

There are three groups of values Digital, Analogs and Integer. This values generating by xml.cgi:

```
 getParams(xml.cgi?D|1|3|I|1|3|A|1|3);
```

and generate this xml:

```
  <PCOWEB><PCO>
<DIGITAL>
<VARIABLE>
<INDEX>1</INDEX>
<VALUE>0</VALUE>
</VARIABLE>
<VARIABLE>
<INDEX>2</INDEX>
<VALUE>0</VALUE>
</VARIABLE><VARIABLE>
<INDEX>3</INDEX>
<VALUE>0</VALUE>
</VARIABLE>
</DIGITAL>
<INTEGER>
<VARIABLE>
<INDEX>1</INDEX>
<VALUE>0</VALUE>
</VARIABLE>
<VARIABLE>
<INDEX>2</INDEX>
<VALUE>0</VALUE>
</VARIABLE>
<VARIABLE>
<INDEX>3</INDEX>
<VALUE>0</VALUE>
</VARIABLE>
</INTEGER>
<ANALOG>
<VARIABLE>
<INDEX>1</INDEX>
<VALUE>5.0</VALUE>
</VARIABLE>
<VARIABLE>
<INDEX>2</INDEX>
<VALUE>5.9</VALUE>
</VARIABLE>
<VARIABLE>
<INDEX>3</INDEX>
<VALUE>0.0</VALUE>
</VARIABLE>
</ANALOG>
</PCO></PCOWEB>
```

How dynamically get this values  and place on html using Java and place to the right place by DIV.

Comment: Hard to read...  You may want to try rewording and indenting your XML example (all caps is hard on the eyes as well, but XML is case sensitive, so...).  Also, you may want to mention if you can use AJAX.

Comment: all caps generate my xml.cgi this is part of my hardware. I can't change this. On this hardware are  a small server. so I need get this values by index... and place on my page using Java and <div id="some_id"></div>  and dynamically refresh it every 5sec.

Comment: JavaScript. Small server on this device does not support PHP